discord oauth2 login session persistence lost on mobile after redirect
I'm working on a Discord login integration for my app, and it's mostly working, but I'm running into an issue with authentication persistence.
The login works fine on desktop — I'm redirected to Discord, authorize, and then I'm redirected back to my app. All perfectly fine.
But when I do it from mobile, for some reason it seems it is losing the session and user is not logged in.
If I try to debug on backend I can retrieve user data, so this means the problem arise on redirect to the app.
Here's a summary of my setup:
OAuth Flow:

User Authorization: When the user clicks the login button, they're redirected to Discord's OAuth page.
Callback: After the user authorizes the app, Discord redirects back to my /auth/discord/callback endpoint with an authorization code.
Access Token: I exchange this code for an access token and retrieve the user's data
The user is successfully logged in via Discord, and I redirect them to the profile page, where I can display their information.

I am not sure then why is this working properly on desktop but not on mobile, I suspect is something about either session or cookies handling on mobile browser.
Here is some code for reference:
./config/discordOauth.js
require('dotenv').config();
const DiscordOauth2 = require('discord-oauth2');

const oauth = new DiscordOauth2({
  clientId: process.env.DISCORD_CLIENT_ID,
  clientSecret: process.env.DISCORD_CLIENT_SECRET,
  redirectUri: process.env.DISCORD_REDIRECT_URI,
});

module.exports = oauth;

./config/sessionConfig.js
require('dotenv').config();

const sessionConfig = {
  secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  cookie: {
    maxAge: 60000 * 60 * 24,
    httpOnly: true,
    sameSite: 'None', 
    secure: true, 
  },
};

module.exports = sessionConfig;

./controller/authController.js
const oauth = require('../config/discordOauth');
const User = require('../models/User'); 

const crypto = require('crypto');

exports.authDiscord = (req, res) => {
  const state = crypto.randomBytes(16).toString('hex');
  req.session.state = state; 
  console.log('Generated state:', state);
  console.log('Session state before redirect:', req.session.state);

  const url = oauth.generateAuthUrl({
    scope: ['identify', 'email', 'guilds'],
    state: state,
  });

  res.redirect(url);
};

exports.discordCallback = async (req, res) => {
  const { state, code } = req.query;

  if (state !== req.session.state) {
    return res.status(400).send('State mismatch');
  }

  try {
    const token = await oauth.tokenRequest({
      code,
      grantType: 'authorization_code',
      redirectUri: process.env.DISCORD_REDIRECT_URI,
    });

    const discordUser = await oauth.getUser(token.access_token);
    const guilds = await oauth.getUserGuilds(token.access_token); 
    let user = await User.findOne({ discordId: discordUser.id });
    
    if (!user) {
      // Create a new user
      console.log('New user created:', user);
    } else {
      // Update existing user
      console.log('User updated:', user);
    }

    req.session.user = user;
    req.session.token = token.access_token; 

    res.cookie('token', token.access_token, {
      httpOnly: true,  
      secure: true, 
      sameSite: 'None', 
    });

    req.session.save((err) => {
      if (err) {
        console.error('Error saving session:', err);
      }
      res.redirect(`${process.env.FRONTEND_URL}/profile`);
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error during OAuth process:', error);
    res.status(500).send('Error during OAuth2 process');
  }
};

./routes/authRoutes.js
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const authController = require('../controllers/authController');

router.get('/auth/discord', authController.authDiscord);
router.get('/auth/discord/callback', authController.discordCallback);

module.exports = router;


Is there anything I am unaware of regarding the mobile browser?
I find it weird that on desktop it works without any flaws while on mobile it doesn't.
I don't get any error other than 401 when redirected to my main page where I try to access other backend enpoints protected by a middleware to check for user authentication
module.exports = (req, res, next) => {
  if (req.session && req.session.user) {
    return next();  
  } else {
    return res.status(401).send('Unauthorized'); 
  }
};

